# parse.com arduino yun boolean data type not recognised

Tags: parse-platform, arduino, boolean

I'm trying to save an object to my parse database from my arduino. Most of the time it's working fine (for strings and numbers) but when i try and send to a boolean column i can't get it to work.
The serial monitor tells me it expects a string and i've tried

"true"
"True"
"1"
1
true
"yes"
(and all the false equivalents)

and non of them work they all load to parse as (undefined) or fail to load at all (in the cases where they weren't strings)

i'm out of ideas and can't find any examples. Anyone got a suggestion of another format i could try??

Thanks as always! :)

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that Parse.com has some weird behaviour from the arduino SDK. 
If i try and save to a boolean value from arduino to a column that was manually created on the parse engine it doesn't seem to save and gives an error saying something like it failed because it got a boolean when it expected a string (though no idea why it is expecting a string). 
I can't see any issue with the table or parse connection as it saves strings and numbers to that table fine - just not booleans.

However, if you create the class/table and boolean column from the arduino then it will accept

true or false

(no brackets just as a straight arduino boolean)
Absolutely no idea why. I have two tables on parse.com both with columns of the same name both of type boolean - one created from the arduino, one manually on the parse.com front end. The arduino created column will save a boolean from the arduino- the other will not as it expects a string. Very odd - but the SDK is experimental i guess!